# Error inflating ConstraintLayout from a specific context

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to inflate a fragment containing a constrain layout but I got this error :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: modular.testing, PID: 12485
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/smartmoov.solutions.generateddynamiclib-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64, /product/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:616)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:798)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:738)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:869)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:832)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
```

Let me explain my architecture a little special. I have a main application which loads other "modules". Modules are application with the same sharedUserId attributes containing codes and ressources.

To load ressources of the module I must specify the context of the LayoutInflater like in this exemple of Fragment :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Context context = getActivity().createPackageContext("insert package name here", Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.fragment_generated_dynamic_lib, container, false);
}
```

It's working well if use LinearLayout but I got a strange ClassNotFound error. I've implement ContrainstLayout in my gradle file (even with the force option) and checked with ClassyShark if the ContrainstLayout lib is included.

I saw on SO some similar problems when using contraint layout in notification, I don't know if there is a link !

Thanks in advance if you can help  ;)

EDIT :

After some experiments, if I launch an activity, even from an inflated fragment, the activitiy can inflate correctly a fragment containing a ConstraintLayout.

Then I compare their classLoader :

```
GeneratedDynamicLib: onCreateView: getClassLoader() ? dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/smartmoov.solutions.generateddynamiclib-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64, /product/lib64]]]
ActivityTest: onCreateView: getClassLoader ? dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/smartmoov.solutions.generateddynamiclib-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/smartmoov.solutions.generateddynamiclib-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64, /product/lib64]]]
```

I know the context is different because for the acitivity I use Intent and startActivity but in the fragment I use :

```
getActivity().createPackageContext(getClass().getPackage().getName(), Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
```

Do you know if it's possible to create the same Context or ClassLoader than the activity ?